# What's a good templating engine for a .NET console app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms, template-engine, spark-view-engine

We're looking for a fast, flexible way of generating templated content (in this case personalized e-mails in text and HTML format) from a .NET console application.

We have no VirtualPathProvider and no valid HttpContext.Current, which, from our initial experiments, means it's going to be very, very hard to use the WebForms view engine, and any of the other .NET web view engines (Spark, Razor) are going to need extensive plumbing to make them think they're running in a web app.

I want to do something like:

```
var customerTemplateData = GetTemplateDate(customer);
var htmlBody = templateEngine.Render("template.html", customerTemplateData);
var textBody = templateEngine.Render("template.txt", customerTemplateDate);
SendMail("me@mydomain.com", customer.Email, "Hey there!", htmlBody, textBody);
```

and I want to do it with complex nested data, lots of lists inside lists, up to 1,000 times a minute.

Any recommendations for dedicated template engines or for ways to run the Web view engines in a standalone context would be most appreciated :)

Thanks,

Dylan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for some guidance on how you'd achieve this with Spark, there is a fully functional [Email and Text Templating Sample available here](https://github.com/loudej/spark/tree/master/src/Samples/DirectUsage/EmailOrTextTemplating/) in the Spark source code.

It should be noted that there is actually no dependency that this sample has on HttpContext or any other web infrastructure for that matter. It's completely independant and could just as easily run as a console application.

Hope this helps,
All the best,
Rob

Comment: I did finally manage to get Spark doing what I need, but it took a bit of hacking - two tiny changes to the core library, and injecting a SparkSettings directly into the engine instead of relying on the App.config file (for some reason it couldn't load the SparkConfiguration handler in a console app?)

Working code's in my Github fork; accept my pull request and I'll accept your answer. :)

Comment: I've got the pull req open in a tab :) Just waiting to get some time to properly go through it - but it's looking very good. Thanks for the contribution - that is more valuable than an accepted answer ;)

Comment: OK it's pulled in, so you can ref the main repo now. Thanks again for the contribution. No changes to the core lib needed, but I fixed your sample to use it correctly. Have fun with it! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few ways of creating templated content from the command line, NVelocity is an example, but also recently we're released our wrapper of the Razor parser on CodePlex ( http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ ) which I think is worth a look into.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another,
[StringTemplate Template Engine](http://www.stringtemplate.org/).

However, I am attention to RezorTemplateEngine!